# Which data should I encrypt to create a secure ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, security, encryption

I'm creating a web application that will use a lot of ajax calls. The application will hold user's personal data. In the ajax calls are variables used like Id, profile_id, message_id etc.. to complete operations like adding posts to profiles, getting connections, etc..

I want to make the calls so **secure as posible**. I already implemented `crsf` in the `$.post` calls. What kind of varibales of the ajax calls must/should I encrypt and which not?

Example of a ajax call (simplified):

```
function post_msg(profile_id, msg) {
        var json_data = new Object(); 

        json_data.profile_id = profile_id;
        json_data.msg = msg;

        var data_str = JSON.stringify(json_data);

        $.post("/ajax/get_posts", { data: data_str, csrf_key: "950egg22b771xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1a"}, func_that_does_something_with_ret_data);
}

//Some where else in the front-end
$('#button').click(function() {
    var msg = $('#input').value();

    post_msg(1, msg); //should I encrypt the id?
});
```

Comment: There's no way to protect your data. Anything you write in JavaScript can easily be reversed.

Comment: @RobW — It is possible to implement public key encryption in JS, which wouldn't be reversible without the private key, but there are so many other attack vectors that it wouldn't be very useful to do so.

Comment: Are you connecting to host through HTTP or HTTPS? If you use HTTPS then I don't think you need any other form of encryption. HTTPS should be fine as it is. If you only use HTTP then maybe firstly try to switch to HTTPS? This will give you much more than any other form of custom encryption.

Comment: Do you currently encrypt data that's sent as regular HTML?

Comment: csrf_key is not for data encryption but for Cross-Site Request Forgery protection

Comment: @Zuljin The application will be in Https. The https is a single secure connection between client and host, but a 'evil' user still can change the id's of the call to retrieve or put data to/from db, right?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I know, but it's still a security thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think about encrypting individual bits of data. If security is important, run the entire transaction across HTTPS.

Comment: The application will be in Https. The https is a single secure connection between client and host, but a 'evil' user still can change the id's of the call to retrieve or put data to/from db, right?

Comment: @Sven — You said you were concerned about protecting the user's personal data. It is their data so you don't need to protect it from them.

Comment: @Sven — If you want to stop users accessing other user's data, then encryption isn't the solution. You need authentication + authorization. It doesn't matter what they *request*, just don't give them data they aren't allowed to see.

Comment: Thx Quentin! I'm gonna remove the encryption and implement authentication & authorization on the requested page of the ajax call. The user's id is saved in the session after the login, so i can use that id to check if the user is allowed to execute the request.

Comment: Don't remove the encryption. Protecting user data from being intercepted over HTTP is important too! Keep HTTPS turned on.

Comment: Then I will let it be :P One more question; should I add SSL to the development server, or just develop without SSL, and on the live server (with ssl) a rewrite rule to change all the http to https?

Comment: Probably best to test both of them separately, + maybe a test of both for performance reasons. Don't forget to only allow reasonably secure TLS ciphersuites